# In Azure-devops, trying to create a drive using PowerShell New-PSDrive, no errors are returned, but mapping is not created

Tags: powershell, yaml, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I am trying to create a very simple yaml script that will map a drive to a remote machine, (that Azure can access), create a folder on a target machine and copy a file to that folder.

I want to use PowerShell to do it as I want to run a few more lines of code+jobs once the file is copied.

```yaml
...
stages:
- stage: CommonStage
  jobs:
  - job: CommonJob
    pool: 
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Create folder'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: | 
          $mappedName = "z"
          $machine = "$(MachineIPAddress)"

          # Map the drive
          New-PSDrive -Verbose -Name $mappedName -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\$machine\c$\"   

          # Set the location to the drive we _just_ mapped.
          z:
...
```

From the output I can tell that the folder is mapped, but I get an error as soon as I try and set the location to it.

```
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                               ---------------
z                                      FileSystem    \\aa.bb.cc.dd\c$\                                             

Set-Location : Cannot find path 'z:\' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Location $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (z:\:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Why is the folder that I just mapped to not found?
If the mapping did not work, (or had not worked), why did I not get an error?

If I include `Get-PSDrive` I can see that my drive is mapped, but I cannot do anything with it.

```
...
z                                      FileSystem    \\aa.bb.cc.dd\c$\
```

Finally, how can I map the drive and use it in my pipeline?

Comment: What's your purpose to map the azure VM C drive? You are using Microsoft-hosted agent, which will connect to Azure VM with `public IP`, checked on my side, only `internal ip` can be succeed for the `New-PSDrive` command(i created 2nd Azure VM for checking). Hence, you can use self-hosted agent with internal IP. Or as per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-quick-create-use-windows), use storage account and file share  as an intermediary, when means you mapp the file share both on target VM and agent machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check with the following steps to fix the issue:

1. Log in to the agent machine, manually try the same PowerShell script on the machine. Ensure the script can work as expected.
2. Set up a new self-hosted agent on the agent machine. Use the **`username`** and **`password`** you log in the machine as the [**authentication**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops#authentication-options) of the new agent.
3. Use the new agent to run the pipeline job.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it is possible to SSH or RDP to an agent and try and run a command.